# What muscles are used to create and oppose posterior pelvic tilt when the upper body is leaning forward?

Tags: muscle, anatomy

I have no difficulty tilting my pelvis in a seated or standing position, or in a quarter squat when my body is upright. When my upper body is tilted forward 30 degrees, however, curling my tailbone forward for a posterior pelvic tilt leads to a familiar juddering that I recognize as the sign of a poorly coordinated muscle group. Does a different muscle take over in this position, or are the spinal erectors pulling the pelvis in an anterior tilt direction and not being very good at relaxing?

I don't think it's an issue with hip flexibility, my hip hinge is fine.

Comment: Do you feel the juddering in your glutes??

Comment: That's a good question. No, it feels as though it's right around the tailbone -- as though there's a muscle pulling the tailbone down, and also tucking it to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad terms the quadricep and hamstring/glueteus as well as the psoas and piriformis are responsible.

Yoga: Cat Camels, Pigeon Pose.
Stretching: Deep Lunge, Toe Touches, Butterfly Stretch.

Comment: I googled a psoas activating exercise and it did seem to help, though it may be placebo. Thanks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tG96Rog81U